# How can we give a service Listen access to multiple Topics (but not all of them) on an Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, connection-string, event-listener, policy, azure-servicebus-topics

We have a microservice which forwards Salesforce Event Bus Channels to Azure Service Bus Topics.
We want to give Microsoft Dynamics access to some -- but not all -- of the Topics.

While I could create a listen policy for each Topic and then give the Dynamics 365 developers a dozen connection strings, this seems less than ideal.

Is there a way to create a policy and connection string which would allow listening to an arbitrary collection of Topics on the Azure Service Bus without granting access to all of the Topics on the same bus?

Comment: In the past, it could be achieved with STS/custom policies. I'll see if someone could add a meaningful answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't have a SAS for multiple entities, but you can leverage [Azure AD based authentication/authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas) instead by giving your app registration access to multiple entities.

Another option would be to [chain entities with auto forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) by creating a single final queue where are messages are forwarded from the topics that you need, and dynamics would have access only to the final queue. When you need to add/remove topics, it would only have to be done in Service Bus and dynamics would just continute to listen on the same final queue.